# Distinguishing static fragments from dynamic ones

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-lifecycle

Writing an android library, I'm listening to fragments' life-cycle using `supportFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks`. Having the fragment object in the callbacks, how can I check whether the fragment is a static fragment (defined in the xml file) or a dynamic one (defined in a container like FrameLayout)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself and it was actually a pretty easy one.

The Fragment class has a method called `isInLayout()` which returns true if the fragment has been created using the `<fragment>` tag.

Here is the documentation for the method:

> ### public final boolean isInLayout ()
>
> Return true if the layout is included as part of an activity view hierarchy via the `<fragment>` tag. This will always be true when fragments are created through the `<fragment>` tag, *except* in the case where an old fragment is restored from a previous state and it does not appear in the layout of the current state.